# Count occurrence of words in a sentence using Java

Tags: java, string

I have written a code snippet to  read a sentence and print the words in the sentence along with their count of occurence.

Example:
String = Java is a language. java is easy and i like Java
Expected output :
Java =3, is=2 a=1, language=1, easy=1, and=1 i=1, like=1

I want to achieve it by using two nested for loops but I am missing something and the code is broken.  Here is the snippet

```
package corejava;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class DuplicateStringOccurence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String myString = " Java is a language. java is easy and i like Java";
  String[] wordsInMySentence = getWords(myString);
  Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  
  int countOfOccurence = 1;
  
  // outloop i, innerlop j
  
  for(int i=0;i<wordsInMySentence.length;i++) {
      if (myMap.containsKey(wordsInMySentence[i])) {
          countOfOccurence=1;
          continue;
      }
      for(int j=i+1;j<wordsInMySentence.length;j++) 
      {
          if (wordsInMySentence[i].equalsIgnoreCase(wordsInMySentence[j])) {
              // match found
              countOfOccurence++;
          }
          myMap.put(wordsInMySentence[i], countOfOccurence);
      }
  }
  
  // print the duplicates and counts
  
  for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue().toString());
    }
  }
  
    

    private static String[] getWords(String myString) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] wordsInMySentence = myString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
        // create the array of words from the sentence
        
        for (String s:wordsInMySentence) {
        //  System.out.println(s);
        }
        return wordsInMySentence;
    }

}
```

I am not getting the expected output. I want to correct this piece of code . Can someone guide what  is the mistake here?

Comment: Try to use merge method of the Map<K,V> - it's available since 1.8.

Comment: `if (myMap.containsKey(wordsInMySentence[i]))` - shouldn't this be tested for false?  Also why bother with the inner loop.  Convert all words to LC.

Comment: Maybe put the countOfOccurence = 1 outside if and also the myMap.put outside the inner loop.

Comment: @Barracuda that's the answer

Comment: @Barracuda Solved like a charm. thanks

Comment: @mack the put is fine- it's just redundant to put new values again, and you can do it once after the loop. The problem is in countOfOccurence, because when it finds a new word, it uses the count of the previous word where it stopped. You can also just put countOfOccurence = 1 after the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using `java8` you can do like below :

First split you string by using regex `("[. ]+")` and store that into List.

Then using `Collectors.toMap` ,

```
 toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper,BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

It takes below three arguments :

1. KeyMapper -  `k -> k.toLowerCase()`
2. ValueMapper -  `k -> 1`
3. MergeFunction  - Here `Integer::sum`

You can refer doc [Collectors.toMap(keyMapper,valueMapper,mergeFunction)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

```
public class WordCount {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sentense= "Java is a language.java is easy and i like Java";

        List<String> list = Stream.of(sentense).map(k -> k.split("[. ]+")).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Map<String, Integer> countMap= list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.toLowerCase(), k -> 1, Integer::sum));

       System.out.println(countMap);
   // Output : {a=1, java=3, like=1, and=1, i=1, language=1, is=2, easy=1}

   }
}
```

Comment: Your regex should be `"[. ]+"` (based on the desired output)

Comment: Or use `k.split("\\W+")`

Comment: you need to handle , " ' : all special characters. So instead of adding each one by one use `\W`

Comment: The code incorrectly counts leading and trailing whitespace, e.g: "   Java is..."

Comment: @DavidSoroko What about if we use .trim() there.

Answer (score 0):

With Map data structure you need only one for loop.
 Here is one solution using basic for loop:

```java
        String sentense= "Java, is a language.java is easy and i like Java";
        
        String[] words = sentense.split("\\W+");
        
        Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        for(String word : words) {
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            Integer count = countMap.containsKey(word)? countMap.get(word) + 1 : 1;
            countMap.put(word, count);
        }

       System.out.println(countMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the handy `merge` method to keep track of the sums

```kotlin
    private static String[] getWords(String myString) {
        return myString.trim().split("\\W+");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "\tJava is a  language. java is easy and i like Java   ";
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap();

        for (String word : getWords(myString)) {
            myMap.merge(word.toLowerCase(), 1, Integer::sum);
        }
        System.out.println(myMap);
    }
```